# How to place a row (subtotal) below a stream of populated data when its size is unknown?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

The question is pretty straight forward: If I'm using a formula that will populate the column with a unknown range of data, no matter what formula it is (filter, query, arrayformula, unique), how would I make a row, or at least a cell, to be automatically placed right bellow the last cell of the populated data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I would use:

```
=LET(data,<your_formula>,
     {data;SUM(data)})
```

For example:

```
=LET(data,FILTER(A1:A5,B1:B5),
     {data;SUM(data)})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try placing your formula inside an array. For example, to add a Total row right after a QUERY, you can use this:

```
= { QUERY ; { "TOTAL" , SUM(range) } }
```